# Почему в плагине Adrotate Configuration errors?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, config

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с установленным [плагином баннерной рекламы Adrotate](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/adrotate/). Все обновлено до последней версии. Хочу добавить новое рекламное место с названием **Рекламное место 13**, в которое поместил код с картинками полностью идентичный **Рекламное место 12**, который в работе:

```
<a href=" http://adt.by/priglashaem-vseh-prinyat-uchastie-v-fotokonkurse-v-ramkah-kubka-adt-by/" target="_blank"><img src="%image%" title="Фотоконкурс"/></a>
```

устанавливаю дату и время, но оно сбивается и в менеджере рекламы отображает желтым цветом показывает **Configuration errors**, причем нигде не комментирует почему
[image: картинка]
Гадаю на кофейной гуще, уже и делал в настройках re-avaluate-all-ads и optimize database - не помогает. Что делать посоветуете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае решение оказалось довольно простым - я выбрал объявление, содержащее ошибку и насильно применил над ним операцию **renew** (for 1 year) в разделе **manage adverts**